# password verify keeps returning wrong login credentials php

Tags: php, mysqli

Every single time I try to log in, I tried several times with accounts in the database with passwords I am sure of, these are hashed then inserted into the database. However, whenever I use `password_verify`, I keep getting the error handler put in that says that the user has put wrong login credentials. Tried creating another user that contains ASCII character to check for encoding errors, but still didn't work.

```
<?php

require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)) {
        header('location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields');
        exit();
    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header('location: ../login.php?error=stmtfailed');
            exit();
        } 

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                

        $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData) == 0) { 
            header('location: ../login.php?error=usernonexistant');
            exit();
        }

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData);
        $pwdHashed = $row['pwd'];
        $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);      

        if ($checkPwd === false) {
            header('location: ../login.php?error=wronglogincredentials');
            exit();
        } else if ($checkPwd === true) {    /*review this bruh*/ 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['uid'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData) ['uid'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData) ['username'];
            header('location: ../index.php');
            exit();
        } 
    }
} else {
    header('location: ../login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you invoking `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` four times?

Comment: Please add this command after this line: `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`: `print_r($resultData); die();` and attach the output to your question

Comment: `$resultData` is not a query, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` won't work that way ... and you have 2 `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and a total mixup of `stmt` and regular calls

Comment: @Reflective No, 4X `mysqli_fetch_assoc` ...

Comment: @Adam P. this is what I get : mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Comment: @Reflective so what is it? And how do you select all from database where smthg when using prepared statements and put them in an arrray?

Comment: please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  and see what `mysqli_query` does

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @Reflective I have absolutely no idea what you are saying. I am sorry but your comments don't make much sense. Can you explain this better?

Comment: $sql = 'select * from tablename';
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

Comment: @Reflective But that doesn't use prepared statements does it..?

Comment: @Reflective OP uses prepared statements. `mysqli_query()` doesn't apply here

Comment: @Dharman yeah exactly. What can i use here instead to get data from a column?

Comment: @samervjr You are almost there, but you are not using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` correctly. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` four times, but you only have one row. This function is not idempotent. Each time you call it, the internal pointer moves on to the next row. You have complicated the code way too much. If mysqli is too difficult for you, please try PDO.

The same code can be rewritten to make it simpler. After some small refactoring the code will look like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    header('location: ../login.php');
    exit();
}

if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
    header('location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields');
    exit();
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
$stmt->execute();
$resultData = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $resultData->fetch_assoc();

if (!$row) {
    header('location: ../login.php?error=usernonexistant');
    exit();
}

$checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd']);

if (!password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd'])) {
    header('location: ../login.php?error=wronglogincredentials');
    exit();
}

$_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
header('location: ../index.php');
exit();
```

In the above code, I removed the remaining three calls to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and used OO-style which is much easier to read. Be sure to enable mysqli error reporting. Read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)